# What does the phrase "Perfect for all time" mean?

Tags: hebrews

Heb 10:14 BSB

> because by a single offering He has made perfect for all time those who are being sanctified.

Does this mean that All sins past and future are already forgiven?

Does this mean that they are wholistically Holy?

How does this affect the other scriptures that talk about the danger of Apostasy and losing salvation?

Answer (score 1):

Heb 10:14 BSB

> because by a single offering He has made perfect for all time those who **are being sanctified**.

He has made perfect
τετελείωκεν (teteleiōken)
Verb - **Perfect Indicative** Active - 3rd Person Singular

are sanctified.
ἁγιαζομένους (hagiazomenous)
Verb - **Present Participle** Middle or Passive - Accusative Masculine Plural
Strong's 37: From hagios; to make holy, i.e. purify or consecrate; to venerate.

New American Standard Bible

> For by one offering He has perfected for all time those who **are sanctified**.

This is about justification and not salvation in general. Jesus' one-time sacrifice on the cross is the means of justification for all people for all time, in the past, present, and future.

At https://biblehub.com/hebrews/10-14.htm, 11 versions use "being sanctified" or "being made holy"; 16 versions use "are sanctified" and such.

What does the phrase "Perfect for all time" mean?

The perfect indicative shows that it was a done deal. Jesus' one-time sacrifice perfectly fulfilled all animal sacrifices. No more animal sacrifices are needed.

Comment: Great answer +1. However your last sentence takes the spot like away from the people who are sanctified to the Means of their perfection.  Are you saying that it simply means the animal system was fufiled by Jesus ?

Comment: "However your last sentence takes the spot like away from the people who are sanctified to the Means of their perfection."?

Comment: Are you saying that it simply means the animal system was fufiled by Jesus ?  Yes :)

Comment: He has perfected for all time "those". That's persons not systems

Comment: +1, I modified. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The author of Hebrews compared Jesus' sacrifice through his death to that of the sacrificial system in Mosaic law.

> When he said above, “You have neither desired nor taken pleasure in sacrifices and offerings and burnt offerings and sin offerings” (these are offered according to the law), 9 then he added, “Behold, I have come to do your will.” He does away with the first in order to establish the second. 10 And by that will we have been sanctified through **the offering of the body of Jesus Christ once for all**.
> 11 And every priest stands daily at his service, offering repeatedly the same sacrifices, which can never take away sins. 12 But when **Christ had offered for all time a single sacrifice for sins**, he sat down at the right hand of God,
> (Heb. 10:8–12, ESV)

τετελείωκεν (he has perfected) means *completed, finished*; the perfect tense means the action is complete, but the emphasis is on the results that continue.  It is the same word used in the aorist tense for "to **fulfill** the Scripture" (John 19:28).

It is similar to the perfect tense verb τετέλεσται ("it is finished" John 19:30), which translated the verb for restitution in the Septuagint (LXX).  See [Tetelestai - What did Jesus really say in John 19:30 assuming he spoke Aramaic or Hebrew?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47848/tetelestai-what-did-jesus-really-say-in-john-1930-assuming-he-spoke-aramaic-o/47862#47862)

**Thus,**

> For by a single offering he has perfected for all time those who are being sanctified. (Heb 10:14, ESV)

**means all restitution and sanctification is done with Christ's sacrifice for ever more.**

Senses of τελειόω in the New Testament (Logos Bible Software).

[image]

Senses τελέω of in the New Testament

[image]