# How should we understand the connection between Ps 2 and Heb 1, ‘becoming heir’?

Tags: jesus, psalms, hebrews

> He said to me, ‘You are My son, today I have fathered you.
> 8‘Ask it of Me, and I will certainly give the nations as your inheritance, and the ends of the earth as your possession. Ps 2:8

> But in these last days He has spoken to us by His son whom He appointed heir of all things Heb 1:2

Answer (score 2):

There are several texts about the promised Messiah becoming heir:

- Ps 2:8 - Ask Me, and I will make the nations Your inheritance, the ends of the earth Your possession.

Such an idea is consistent with the promised Messiah being the first-born of God and thus the inheritor of all things:

- Ps 2:7 - I will proclaim the decree spoken to Me by the LORD: “You are My Son; today I have become Your Father.
- Ps 89:27 - I will indeed appoint him as My firstborn, the highest of the kings of the earth.

Heb 1:2 announces the fulfillment of these promises:

- Heb 1:2 - But in these last days He has spoken to us by His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, and through whom He made the universe.

As part of this "inheritance", Jesus was also High Priest (Heb 8:1, etc), and king of the New Covenant (Matt 1:1, 20, 9:27, 12:23, 15:22, 20:30, 15, 21:9, 15, Mark 10:35, Luke 1:32, 33, 18:38, 39, John 1:49, Acts 13:32-37, Heb 1:8).

This was presumably on the basis of the victory over death, the grave and sin that Christ achieved at the resurrection following His crucifixion.

Comment: Thx, curious about the last line. Everything was 'achieved' at death, resurrection was a forgone conclusion to that successful death.

Comment: @steveowen - not everything was fully achieved but Satan was effectively a defeated foe at the resurrection.  However, his final destruction must wait until that predicted in Rev 20 occurs - Satan will be destroyed.  Further, Jesus' final absolute authority must wait until Rev 11:15.

Comment: "Satan was effectively a defeated foe at the resurrection" not so. By his death he might break the power of him who holds the power of death—that is, the devil Heb2:14 and many others - it is by death not resurrection. Col 1:22, Rom 5:10, Eph 2:16

Comment: @steveowen - OK but the death and resurrection were only 3 days apart.  Further, If Christ was not raised, then His death would have been in vain.  It was the resurrection that defeated death.

Comment: :) seriously, he died the perfect death without sin, that’s all that was required! A fait accompli. The rest was a mere formality.

Comment: @steveowen - that is true with hind-sight.  But it was crucial according to 1 Cor 15

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47848/tetelestai-what-did-jesus-really-say-in-john-1930-assuming-he-spoke-aramaic-o/47862#47862

Answer (score 1):

One  connection is God the Father speaking,  either to His Son or speaking to "us" through His Son.   It is said in both scriptures, Jesus is the heir of the nations, the heir of all things, which means that God the Father owned everything and now has all things given to His Son.

These have been given to Him after he grew up so to speak, being trained, disciplined by the Father, growing from a boy, servant to God being proud to call Him His Son.

> Although He was a Son, He learned obedience from what He suffered. Hebrews 5:8

It's interesting how God  called Jesus His servant a few times.

Here's the definition of that meaning:
Definition: a child, boy, youth
Usage: (a) a male child, boy, (b) a male slave, servant; thus: a servant of God, especially as a title of the Messiah,

Cognate: 3816 país – a child under training (strict oversight), emphasizing their ongoing development necessary to reach their highest (eternal) destiny.

Here are a few scriptures where Jesus is referred to as His servant, Which can mean he was a child under training.

> The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, the God of our fathers, has glorified His servant Jesus. You handed Him over and rejected Him before Pilate, even though he had decided to release Him.  Acts 3:13

> When God raised up His Servant, He sent Him first to you to bless you by turning each of you from your wicked ways.” Acts 3:26

> In fact, this is the very city where Herod and Pontius Pilate conspired with the Gentiles and the people of Israel against Your holy servant Jesus, whom You anointed. Acts 4:27

Jesus was shown to the world to be worthy of  being  His Son by His faith in God the Father  which was made perfect Through the obedience dying on the cross.

In a way, it's reminiscent of Abraham wanting his very own son, so his son could be his heir of everything he had.

Comment: Thx, of course, the  first is David speaking prophetically of a yet future event.